# Ejecución de programa Python siempre activo

Tags: python, windows

¿Como hago para ejecutar un ***programa python siempre activo***?

Inicio ejecución con ***Microsoft Visual Studio Community en Windows 11***

El programa se detiene después de un tiempo de inactividad del usuario (cuando se apaga la pantalla).

Pero se requiere que siempre esté activo y realizando actividades programadas.
Requiero que el programa esté siempre activo y que ***no se vea afectado por el screensaver de windows.***

Si el programa python NO está en ejecución, entonces que Windows continúe con su programación de ahorro de energía -como esté programado-, ya sea apagando pantalla, discos, etc.

Pero que mientras esté ejecutandose el programa python -no se detenga-.
***El programa python debe estar siempre activo aun con la pantalla apagada.***

```
import time
import schedule

def PorMinutos():
    print('minutos')
def PorHoras():
    print('horas')


schedule.every(30).minutes.do(PorMinutos)  # Este funcion se ejecutará n minutos.
schedule.every(4).hours.do(PorHoras)  # Esta funcion se ejecutará cada n horas

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time. Sleep(5)
```

Comment: Y porque en lugar de eso, no usas el cron de windows para que se dispare cada x cantidad de tiempo???

Comment: Si es un servidor y va a estar trabajando 24/7, entonces no debes poner "ahorro de energía", si acaso menor uso de CPU. Lo de la pantalla no debería tener que afectar. Tengo scripts en mi datacenter que han ejecutado por años tareas tal como lo describes en tu código. Otra forma, y parece la más recomendable para el caso, puede ser creando un [servicio de Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python+windows+service).